# How I can do row locking in cakephp and postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using postgres database in my cakephp project.
I have a table with some data and a column called "status".
"Status" it's enum and can be "waiting", "in_progress", "completed".

My script has to get the first found record with status=waiting, change the status to "in_progress" and also get the id of this record and all this in one atomic procedure.

The id is needed after the computation to change status to "completed".
There will be many such scripts working in parrallel thats why I need this simple "row locking".

I am using postgres db for the first time - is there any easy way to accomplish this?
Maybe cake supports some convinient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with cakePHP it has no diffrence what kind of DB you have, simply use `$this->Model->find...` modify your status and then '$this->Model->save....`

```
$row = $this->Model->find('first',array('conditions' => array('Model.status' => 'waiting')));
$row['Model']['status'] = 'in progress';
$this->Model->save($row);
(...do something...)

$row['Model']['status'] = 'completed';
$this->Model->save($row);
```

propably you want to run it in loop and put some kind of const as statuses...

Comment: lern about transactions [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/transactions.html)

Comment: If any operation during the status changing, the conflict remains. Let's say, two request process with a very little delay, the later one get the same record before the previous one save the status. Thus how to ensure a record would be find by one process.

Comment: The situation you disscribed would be very rare. Specific solution in this case would depend on what are you doing during in_progress status. Would 0.1% of duplicated operations affect your result? If so, you can try with database lock, some kind of memcache lock, adding random offset to find query or even consider comleatly diffrent technology to solve your problem...